# How to 'Ensure CORS response header values are valid' when querying MongoDB in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I have a page in NextJS which is using getServerSideProps to query MongoDB, one of the resulting fields being the url to an image. Everything is fine and I'm displaying the image.

However, I'm trying to get the dominant colour of the image, using various npm packages, and each time I'm getting 'A cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) request was blocked because of invalid or missing response headers'. How do I resolve this given that I'm running the Mongo query code in getServerSideProps and not through an API endpoint, and therefore unable to send the correct headers to allow 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', as I understand it.

Here's the component:

```
import FastAverageColor from 'fast-average-color'

const Component = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
    fac.getColorAsync(imgSrc)
        .then(color => {
            console.log('average color: ',color)
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
    },[])

    return (
        ...
    )
}

export const getServerSideProps() {
    const pipeline = [...]
    const postdata = await db.collection('posts').aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
    return {
        props: {
            postdata: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(postdata)),
        },
    };
}
```

Any help very gratefully received. I've been searching for a resolution for this for 24 hours and about to go mental :)

Answer (score -1):

Disable CORS on localhost,
in `next.config.js`

```
 module.exports = {
        
    
        //avoiding CORS error, more here: https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-to-enable-cors
        async headers() {
            return [
              {
                // matching all API routes
                source: "/api/:path*",
                headers: [
                  { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
                  { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
                  { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
                  { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
                ]
              }
            ]
        },
    }
```

Modification: (not tested)

```
export const getServerSideProps(ctx) {
// try something like this, the idea is to set headers
const headers = [
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
              { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
            ]
ctx.res.writeHead(302, headers)
const pipeline = [...]
const postdata = await db.collection('posts').aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
    return {
        props: {
            postdata: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(postdata)),
        },
    };
}
```

For sure, you will have some errors (if you take some code), you need to find out how to add headres to your `getServerSideProps`

OR try to install [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors)
And don't forget to restart your locahost project

Comment: Hello illia, thank you for your answer. The problem is, this code affects api routes, but as I'm using getServerSideProps, I'm writing to query code directly, bypassing the API route. This is my problem.

Comment: Did you modify next.config.js file?

Comment: Yes, of course I tried it, but I'm not accessing any API routes

Comment: So you need to add somehow headers to your getServerSide function